# Is my code giving a bad pi result because of a mistake on the code or because of float error?

Tags: python

I have just started learning python and to test if I can do loops correctly I tried to calculate pi through the wallis product.

The code I wrote was like this:

```
pi=[1]
i=0
while i<100:
    i=i+1
    pi=pi+[4*i**2/(4*i**2-1)]
print(pi)
x=1
for y in pi:
    x=x*y
    print(x*2)
```

For some reason this is giving a very very bad approximation of pi and I don't know why. With 100 iterations it should definitely not give 3.13
And even if i increase the number of iterations the improvement is minimal. I know it's a very basic code but I'm just learning this language and I don't see if the mistake is on the floating point error or in my code itself.

Comment: *"With 100 iterations it should definitely not give 3.13"* - Says who?

Comment: You're wrong on your assumption that n=100 should be better and you can read it off any plot of the convergence you find from a trivial search.  You need to mathematically provide proof to support that if you still disagree.

Comment: you are right. it seems I was lucky enough that the first expression of pi i found was one of the slowest to converge.

Comment: Speaking of "slow": Replace the slow `pi=pi+[...]` with the fast `pi+=[...]`.

Comment: The Wallis approximation is very slow to converge: after 1M terms pi is accurate to 5 decimal places. In comparison, the Ramanujan formula is a better approximation after only one term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there is no mistake in your code. It's just a fact that used approximation method (Wallis product) has the worse speed of convergence that you expected. Try to increase the upper bound of product, for example, up to 1000 or further if you want to get a better approximation for this method.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product

Comment: Would be good to show the results with 100, 1000, and further.